# How to Connect two tables using NSDictionary?

Tags: nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

In my iphone design, there are two table views added.

One table view is for displaying the MenuList for hotels using NsDictionary(Like Veg. NonVeg, Beverages..) and the other table view is for displaying the ListItems(Like In veg, i will Have Paneer,Rotti..) . When ever a menuList cell is selected the files inside the selected list needs to to be displayed in the other table view(ListIems).

My problem is

I am confused about

I want to use NsDictionary Alone in this two table . Can anyone give me a simple code for this. i am confused and am a fresher. Thanks In advance if someone teaches me. Please help. iam using xcode5

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize menuDict ;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];

    menuName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Veg", @"NonVeg", @"Beverages", nil];
    menuId = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

    self.menuDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:menuName
                                                     forKeys:menuId];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.menuDict allKeys] count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    static NSString *unifiedID = @"TableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:unifiedID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:unifiedID];

    }

    for (id key in self.menuDict) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [self.menuDict objectForKey:key]);
    }

    NSString *key = [self.menuDict allKeys][indexPath.row];

    NSString *menuNameString = self.menuDict[key];
    NSString *menuIdString = key;
    cell.textLabel.text  = menuNameString;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text  = menuIdString;

    return cell;

}






- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"])
    {
           NSDictionary *vvegDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"Rotti" , @"2", @"Panner",  nil] ;
        DetailTableViewController *tvc = segue.destinationViewController ;
    tvc.vegDict =vvegDict ;




    }


}
```

second table :

// Is this right to declare the lists here same as my first table. Please help me in this one.

```
@interface DetailTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailTableViewController
@synthesize vegName,vegId ;



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    vegName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Rotti", @"Panneer", @"Chappathi", nil];
    vegId = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

    self.vegDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:vegName
                                                forKeys:vegId];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return  1 ;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.vegDict allKeys]count] ;
    return 1 ;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *unifiedID = @"aCellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:unifiedID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:unifiedID];

    }

    for (id key in self.vegDict) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [self.vegDict objectForKey:key]);
    }

    NSString *key = [self.vegDict allKeys][indexPath.row];

    NSString *vegNameString = self.vegDict[key];
    NSString *vegIdString = key;
    cell.textLabel.text  = vegNameString;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text  = vegIdString;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Segues to go from one uitableviewcontroller to other then you can use

```
-prepareForSegue:sender:
```

in this method you can set an NSDictionary property in the destination view controller. You can get the the destination view controller from the the sender argument.

Comment: I have used NSdictionary in my first table which displays menuitems Perfectly at output. i followed the same procedure in my second table for veg Items. But i cant able to make the corresponding list in second table. please explain

Comment: i cant able to add my code. it shows indentation error. can you please help in some other way.. menuName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Veg", @"NonVeg", @"Beverages", nil];
    menuId = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
    
    self.menuDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:menuName
                                                     forKeys:menuId]; i did this in viewdidload of 1st table.

Comment: in row at index path. i have this one . for (id key in self.menuDict) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [self.menuDict objectForKey:key]);
    }
    
    NSString *key = [self.menuDict allKeys][indexPath.row];
    
    NSString *menuNameString = self.menuDict[key];
    NSString *menuIdString = key;
    cell.textLabel.text  = menuNameString;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text  = menuIdString;       this same thing i did it in my second table as vegname and vegDict.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code. Select the code and Use ctrl-k to mark it as code.

Comment: i have added my code. i got struci segue method. i did the same in my second table also. can you tell some better suggestion ?

Comment: If you are trying to send data to the detailViewController then you can define a property in the destination view controller and then set it in the prepare for segue method.

Comment: can you give me a example please by using my code. ?  In my DetailTable, i have the property vegDict.

Comment: tvc.vegDict = <your dictionary object>

Comment: if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"])
    {
        NSDictionary *vvegDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"Rotti" , @"2", @"Panner",  nil] ;
            DetailTableViewController *tvc = segue.destinationViewController ;
        tvc.vegDict =vvegDict ;    
    } i did like this .. but still i cant see my veg list in my second table. why ?

Comment: You have to implement same methods you implemented in first view controller only this time with your wegDict.

Comment: Sir, I dont get you this time. I have a doubt. where should i declare my  lists of particular menu? i.e In second table or Segue method ? Now my output is populated only with menu items. in the second table, Its empty. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps this tutorial would help: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: Sorry Sir. it doesnt help me. Only one doubt. where should I declare my Veglist(Secondtable items )? give me one simple code for that please. I am trying this thing for more than two weeks . please help and dont mistake me

Comment: can you suggest some answer ?

Comment: ahmed sir please help me in this situation. its important for me

Comment: what is the the source of your data? File, Database, or Website?

Comment: Oops. sir. i am not using anything. i just added this alone in my code. is it necessary to use source for NSDictionary ? I have to complete this by today :( suggest me

Comment: i have added my second table also. Expecting your answers and help. its going to help me a lot.

Comment: Are you there sir ? I cant able to send data to other view stil. Help

Comment: sir can you please give me the answer. I need to do this one soon. Help

Comment: sir, i have an updated code for this.. can you help me out ? if so.pls comment. i will edit my post .please